# Using Storybook to show React components in both React & Plain HTML/CSS

Tags: reactjs, storybook

so if I have a React Button component that uses styled component like so:

```
import styled, { css } from "styled-components";
import React from "react";

const Button = ({ theme, children }) => {
  const StyledButton = styled.a`
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    ${theme === "primary" &&
    css`
      color: black;
      background: white;
    `}
    ${theme === "secondary" &&
    css`
      color: white;
      background: black;
    `}
  `;

  return <StyledButton>{children}</StyledButton>;
};

export default Button;
```

Is it possible to display this component, alongside its React code & HTML/CSS code on Storybook? (Without having to hard code the HTML/CSS code in)

I was thinking of using React's `renderToString()` to convert it into HTML and using the styled component's string for the CSS. Not sure if this is possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is a [`storybook` addon](https://storybook.js.org/addons/), not a React API.

See [storysource addon](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/tree/master/addons/storysource).

[image: ing]

Comment: Is there a possibility to show both React components and plain HTML (non JSX) source code side by side. using <Preview withToolbar > addon , can I generate plainHTML  source code for button as well.